# Accessing all pixels in cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

Is this the correct way of accessing all pixels in `cv::Mat`:

```
for( row = 0; row < mat.rows; ++row) 
    {
            for ( col = 0; col < mat.cols; ++col) 
            {



            }
    }
```

Or is there a formula method similar to this formula for an `IplImage *`:

```
temp_ptr = &((uchar*)(img->imageData + (img->widthStep*pt.x)))[pt.y*3];
```

Comment: Do you know `Mat` has one public field called `data` of type `uchar`?

Comment: @Nawaz - Yes sir i know about that, please help me out, i am struggling a bit out here, i know that is the pointer to the data, but how do i cycle through pixels, i can get work with the rgb values with data but not cycle through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the best case, where all the pixels are stored contiguously you should be able to do:

```
uchar* pixel = mat.data;
for(int i = 0; i < mat.rows * mat.cols; ++i) 
{
    // access pixel[0],pixel[1],pixel[2] here
    pixel += 3; // move to next pixel
}
```

To be a bit more generic, but still fast, have a look at the [sample code](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#Mat::isContinuous) mentioned with `Mat::isContinuous()`. The general formula for calculating the address of an element can be seen [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#mat) (Reproduced below).

[image: Address calculation]